# SQL Server Tempdb Restore

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that has tempdb split in to 8 files. There are 3 mdf and 5 ndf files.

I need to move this database via backup and restore. Do I need to make sure that I restore these files? If I do not, will the restoration re-create the tempdb files? and if so, will it only re-create one, or will it maintain the current configuration?

thanks

Comment: there is no need (or point) backing up and restoring tempdb. Simply script out the definition and run on new server

Comment: It is not even possible to backup or restore `tempdb`. It is automatically recreated each time on server startup using whatever file configuration you previously set up for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move tempDB via backup and restore, you should use ALTER DATABASE instead.

Grab the names of the files via the following query:

```
SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb');
GO
```

Then change their locations using a query similar to the following (use the output of the first query as a reference)

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'E:\SQLData\tempdb.mdf');
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'F:\SQLLog\templog.ldf');
GO
```

Restart SQL server and the new files will be re-created in the new locations, you can then just delete the old files.